# Adding this code breaks my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, syntax-error

Adding this code

```
def send_messages
  return if recipient_list.blank?

  recipient_list.each do |recipient|
  recipient = User.find(recipient)
  messages.build(user_id: recipient.id, conversation_id: self.id)
end
```

to my model

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :recipient_list
  after_create :send_messages

  has_many :messages
end
```

causes any reference to my model to throw a

```
syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

from the model... without it my model works perfectly fine. Is there something wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an end to close the do block:

```
def send_messages
  return if recipient_list.blank?

  recipient_list.each do |recipient|
    recipient = User.find(recipient)
    messages.build(user_id: recipient.id, conversation_id: self.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: lolwut. how did I miss that ahahaha. Good eye.

will check as soon as time allows.